# SharePoint 2007 getting modified fields

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I would like to know how we know which fields were updated in a SharePoint List.
I have an eventreciever attached to a list, can i know what changes were made to the list using Eventreciever?

Answer (score 0):

I think a list of changed properties are not directly available as a collection or array ?

Correct me if i am wrong? what are you trying to do ?